# Running android lint error

Tags: android

I'm using android lint tools with eclipse to find potential bugs in my project, but after a few seconds it shows:

> "Running Android Lint encountered a problem"

When I click details, it shows:

> "Failed java.lang.NullPointerException".

Can someone give me some suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Lint Tool indicates errors in XML Layout Files in Resources, check all the layout files, and resolve error.

To See error, you can do from Eclipse Menu-> Windows -> Show View-> Problems.

Comment: my project has no error but warnings ,it shows that "Found bitmap drawable res/drawable/XXXXX.9.png in densityless folder,what I should do to solved that?

Comment: let it be, actually this warning is about, that you should put different drawables in different drawable folders, like drawable-ldpi

Comment: so,let's back to the first question(android lint), I still can't find what cause this error now.It seems baffling.

Answer (score 0):

goto help->install new software -> work with "https://dl.google.com/android/eclipse/"

Note : Make sure you that you are using the https, not the http URL to the update center: https://dl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Now when you restart Eclipse IDE, you should not see any Lint Error pop-up's messages.